# Could not load IBDesignable xib in the Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xib, ibdesignable

I have a `xib` (`childXib`) file linked to its custom `UIView` swift file through its Owner.

This is how I initialize my custom `UIView`:

```
// init for IBDesignable
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds

    addSubview(view)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    addSubview(loadViewFromNib())
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CommentCellView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}
```

When I want to add this `xib` (`childXib`) in another `xib` (`parentXib`), I get the following errors:

> error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of MyRootView: The agent threw an exception.

Where `MyRootView` is the file linked to `parentXib`

> error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent raised a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" exception: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'MyIBDesignableCustomViewFilename'

Where `MyIBDesignableCustomViewFilename` is the file linked to `childXib`.

When I debug it by clicking on `Debug` in `Custom class` from the `Identity inspector`, it doesn't work from that line:

```
let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

All the `xib` files are in `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases`.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Does your xib use a subclassed UIView?  If so, you might want to try casting it to that class.

Comment: Yes they are all subclasses of `UIView`

Comment: Then try `let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! MyCustomView`

Comment: @Nico Do you add CommentCellView.xib into your project, but not just copy only?

Comment: You mean in the `Copy Bundle Resources` of `Build Phases`?

Comment: @Nico https://db.tt/JhX9F0xE I created a sample project for you. If you remove or rename CommentCellView.xib in the project, you will see the errors can be reproduced like you mentioned.

Comment: Ok. I tried your project, added another xib as a container (instead of the storyboard), it works. Then I added two other xibs and I had the problem. Cannot figure out what is it. Here is a link if you want to check it: http://bit.ly/20MtrnN

Comment: @Nico I just checked. In LikesCountView.swift, you missed "@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!" and "@IBAction func likeAction(sender: AnyObject) {}" I have updated the content of my above link. You can download again and search keyword "// Missing before" for the parts I added.

Answer (score 18):

First Step:

I will give you an introduction to IBDesignable and IBInspectable, and show you guys how to take advantage of the new feature. There is no better way to elaborate a feature than creating a demo. So we will build a custom interface called “Rainbow” together.

**IBDesignable and IBInspectable**

With IBDesignable and IBInspectable, developers are allowed to create interface (or view) that renders in Interface Builder in real time. In general, to apply this new feature, all you need to do is create a visual class by subclassing UIView or UIControl and then prefix the class name with @IBDesignable keyword in Swift. If you are using Objective-C, you use IB_DESIGNABLE macro instead. Here is a sample code in Swift:

```
@IBDesignable 
class Rainbow: UIView {
}
```

In older versions of Xcode, you can edit the user-defined runtime attributes to change properties of an object (e.g. layer.cornerRadius) in Interface Builder. The problem is you have to key in the exact name of the properties. IBInspectable takes a step forward. When you prefix a property of the visual class with IBInspectable, the property will be exposed to the Interface Builder such that you can change its value in a much straightforward way:

[image]

Again if you are developing your app in Swift, what you have to do is just prefix your chosen property with the keyword @IBInspectable. Here is a sample code snippet:

```
@IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
 {
     // Update your UI when value changes
 }



@IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
{
     // Update your UI when value changes
 }
```

**Building Your Xcode Project**

Let’s get started by creating a new project in Xcode and choose Single View Application as a template, and name it RainbowDemo. We will use Swift in this project as the programming language, so don’t forget to choose it when creating the project.

Once finished, select the Main.storyboard in the Project Navigator and drag a View object from the Object Library to the View Controller. Change its color to #38334C (or whatever color you want) as well as set its size to 600 by 434. Then put it in the center of the main view. Don’t forget to change the color of the main view to the same color of the view object.
Tip: If you want to change the RGB Color values for your code, just open up your Color Palette and switch to the Sliders tab to alter the RGB values.

Getting confused? No worries. You will understand what I mean after going through the project demo.

With Xcode 6, you have to configure auto layout constraints for the view in order to support all types of iOS devices. Auto Layout is pretty powerful in the latest version of Xcode. For simple constraints, you can just click the Issues option of the Auto Layout menu and choose “Add Missing Contraints”, and Xcode will automatically configure the layout constraints for the view.

[image]

**Creating Custom View Class**

Now that you’ve created the view in storyboard, it’s time to create our custom view class. We’ll use the Swift class template for the class creation. Name it “Rainbow”.

[image]

```
Then insert the following code in the class:

import UIKit

class Rainbow: UIView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

As mentioned before, the visual class is a subclass of UIView. In order to use our custom class in live rendering, we need to override both initializers as shown above. Next split the view by selecting the assistant editor:

[image]

Once done, select the main storyboard in the assistant editor, so you can see what you are building in real time. Remember to change the class name of the view to “Rainbow” under the Identity inspector:

**Implementing IBDesignable Controls**

The first step to enable a control for live rendering is to set the custom view as Designable by prefixing the class name with @IBDesignable:

```
@IBDesignable 
class Rainbow: UIView {
    ...
}
```

It’s kinda simple as you can see. But this simple keyword would make your development much easier. Next, we will add a few properties for setting the colors of the circles. Insert these lines of code in the Rainbow class:

```
@IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: (37.0/255.0), green: (252.0/255), blue: (244.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
@IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: (171.0/255.0), green: (250.0/255), blue: (81.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
@IBInspectable var thirdColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: (238.0/255.0), green: (32.0/255)
```

Here, we predefine each property with a default colour, and tell it to redraw the view each time a user changes its value. Most importantly, we prefix each property with the @IBInspectable keyword. If you go to the Attributes inspectable of the view, you should find these properties visually:

Cool, right? By indicating the properties as IBInspectable, you can edit them visually using color picker.

Okay let’s move to implement the main methods of the Rainbow class, which is used to draw a circle on the screen. Insert the following method in the class:

```
func addOval(lineWidth: CGFloat, path: CGPathRef, strokeStart: CGFloat, strokeEnd: CGFloat, strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor, shadowRadius: CGFloat, shadowOpacity: Float, shadowOffsset: CGSize) {

    let arc = CAShapeLayer()
    arc.lineWidth = lineWidth
    arc.path = path
    arc.strokeStart = strokeStart
    arc.strokeEnd = strokeEnd
    arc.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor
    arc.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor
    arc.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    arc.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    arc.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    arc.shadowOffset = shadowOffsset
    layer.addSublayer(arc)
}
```

[image]

To make the code clean and readable, we create a common method for drawing a full or half circle according to the parameters provided by the caller. It’s pretty straightforward to draw a circle or an arc using CAShapeLayer class. You can control the start and end of the stoke using the strokeStart and strokeEnd properties. By varying the value of stokeEnd between 0.0 and 1.0, you can draw a full or partial circle. The rest of the properties are just used to set the color of a stroke, shadow color, etc. You can check out the official documentation for details of all the properties available in CAShapeLayer.

Next, insert the following methods in the Rainbow class:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Add ARCs
    self.addCirle(80, capRadius: 20, color: self.firstColor)
    self.addCirle(150, capRadius: 20, color: self.secondColor)
    self.addCirle(215, capRadius: 20, color: self.thirdColor)
}

func addCirle(arcRadius: CGFloat, capRadius: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
    let X = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds)
    let Y = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)

    // Bottom Oval
    let pathBottom = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake((X - (arcRadius/2)), (Y - (arcRadius/2)), arcRadius, arcRadius)).CGPath
    self.addOval(20.0, path: pathBottom, strokeStart: 0, strokeEnd: 0.5, strokeColor: color, fillColor: UIColor.clearColor(), shadowRadius: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowOffsset: CGSizeZero)

    // Middle Cap
    let pathMiddle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake((X - (capRadius/2)) - (arcRadius/2), (Y - (capRadius/2)), capRadius, capRadius)).CGPath
    self.addOval(0.0, path: pathMiddle, strokeStart: 0, strokeEnd: 1.0, strokeColor: color, fillColor: color, shadowRadius: 5.0, shadowOpacity: 0.5, shadowOffsset: CGSizeZero)

    // Top Oval
    let pathTop = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake((X - (arcRadius/2)), (Y - (arcRadius/2)), arcRadius, arcRadius)).CGPath
    self.addOval(20.0, path: pathTop, strokeStart: 0.5, strokeEnd: 1.0, strokeColor: color, fillColor: UIColor.clearColor(), shadowRadius: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowOffsset: CGSizeZero)

}
```

The default implementation of the `drawRect` method does nothing. In order to draw circles in the view, we override the method to implement our own drawing code. The `addCircle` method takes in three parameters: arcRadius, capRadius and color. The `arcRadius` is the radius of the circle, while the `capRadius` is the radius of the rounded cap.

The addCircle method makes use of UIBezierPath to draw the arcs and it works like this:

```
First it draws a half circle at the bottom
Next it draws a full small circle at the edge of the arc.
Finally, it draws the other half of the circle
```

In the drawRect method, we call the addCircle method three times with different radius and color. This figure illustrates how the circles are drawn:
[image]

Tip: If you need more information about UIBezierPath, you can check out Apple’s official documentation.

With the IBInspectable properties, you are now free to change the color of each circle right in the Interface Builder without diving into the code:

Obviously, you can further expose arcRadius as an IBInspectable property. I’ll leave it as an exercise for you.

[image]

[image]

for Example code click here: https://github.com/appcoda/Rainbow-IBDesignable-Demo

Comment: Man, this is absolutely insane, the amount of effort for one answer! So much respect @prince.

Comment: Great write up for IBDesignable, but failed to address user's request for XIB files.

Comment: @mobilemonkey agreed. I don't think this answer deserves the bounty.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zi5ac3z1emz906v/FireDatabaseAuthWith%20FB%26Google.zip?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4nmlp6jk6kwmu0/Completion_HandlerDemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zon88ngk4ped7nd/Expandable_Tableview.zip?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vsk7igc6776ycxb/AAByMWxUDyyagJEfxPTayHIBa?dl=0=ALL

Comment: the question was about XIB's involved

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem and I managed to fix it.

**Swift 3**

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: MyView.self)
let view = UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: bundle).instantiate(withOwner: self) as! MyView
```

The important bit is the bundle

Answer (score 0):

For both errors like below:

```
error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of ....
error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent raised a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" exception: Could not load NIB in bundle ...
```

I suggest to have a small quick self verification can help to figure out where the issues should be addressed:

1. Check if .xib files are added correctly in to a project
2. Check if nibName is set correctly, sometimes typo happens here
3. Check if both outlet & action are connect appropriately, include
   codes implementation